# Error with Webpack: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I building an app with React.js and I'm using Babel and Webpack and packages. I was following this tutorial https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/getting-started-with-react-js-using-webpack-and-babel-66549f8fbcb8. I did everything by the instructions and when I compiles with npm start I get the following error:

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.entry['main'] should not contain the item '—' twice.
   -> A non-empty array of non-empty strings
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sparo@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sparo@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users*****\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-03-31T21_48_02_843Z-debug.log

this is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sparo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sparo project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server — mode development — open — hot",
    "build": "webpack — mode production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ringbearer-ramos14325/Sparo.git"
  },
  "author": "Daniel Ramos, Eric Brown II",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ringbearer-ramos14325/Sparo/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ringbearer-ramos14325/Sparo#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "create-react-app": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

and this is the webpack.config file:

```
const path = require("path");
const HWP = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "/src/index.js"),
    output: {
        filename: "build.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/dist")
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HWP(
            {template: path.join(__dirname, "/src/index.html")}
        )
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `webpack.config.js` file?  And seeing your `package.json` might help us figure out your issue as well.

Comment: Sorry for the convoluted code. Im unfamilier with stack overflows code formatting.